# how to load() template file, pass as a variable?

Tags: jquery, load

I am using php, and need to load() this , template content php file into the jquery and pass it to a #div ID to render front-end view.

I am not sure how to load the php file in jquery and then pass it as a variable called repeater which helps build out all the rows combining the template loaded with Ajax (obj) query results.

In the set alert, it pops up as [object Object], no template.
When I write the entire php template content out into jquery as var repeater, it works, but I do not want all that html in jquery. Just load() then read.

Here is the code if this makes any sense

```
$('#pageContent').load('../includes/OrderLookup.php #pageContent');
alert ($('#pageContent').load('OrderLookup.html #pageContent'));
var url = $('#pageContent').load('../includes/OrderLookup.php');
var page = '<div id="pageContent"></div>';
var repeater = $('#pageContent').load('OrderLookup.html #pageContent');

var pageBuildUp='';
for (x in dataArray){
     pageBuildUp += obj.repeater;
    //alert(obj.repeater);
    //pageBuildUp += url;
    pageBuildUp = pageBuildUp.replace('##transactionId##',makeTextSmall(dataArray[x]['blockvalue'],20));
    if (dataArray[x]['description']==''){
        pageBuildUp = pageBuildUp.replace('##orderTotal##','no total amount');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery's `load` to specify a URL and a DOM fragment identifier, it returns the DOM fragment, which is why it is alert as an object. My guess is that you're expecting a string? To do that you would need to change your line starting with `var repeater` to the following:

```
var repeater = $('#pageContent').load('OrderLookup.html #pageContent')[0].outerHTML;
```

However, the idea you're implementing sounds dangerous: It sounds like you're trying to manually parse PHP on the front-end. For a start, wouldn't the PHP be executed before being handed back to you, stripping your tokens? Secondly, using plain Javascript for template parsing is a pain. [JS templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates) has gained huge traction recently in an attempt to make tasks like the one you've just described easier. I personally recommend [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), which has been a boon for me.

Comment: Now the php is being rendered in t back-end and then the Blank Template is being parsed in Jquery to then be processed with Data object from php to pass the variable with values.

I think you have solved our issue.

We will test and update.

**thank you very much Barney, thank you.!!!!!!!!**